# How is the timeofday() system call handled in a VM (Using KVM)?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, kvm

If I modify the timeofday() call at the host kernel will the modified system call be called at the guest kernel or will the HyperVisor Handle it somehow?

Can someone get a detailed answer on what happens behind the scenes?

Plus I want to know how this is done on Kernel Version 3.10.9 and Kernel Version 4.2

Answer (score 2):

KVM requires a processor with hardware virtualization support(VT-x/AMD-V ). In hardware virtualization, all guests interrupts cause a trap on host OS. The host then determines if the interrupt is for itself or for the guest. For former case, host OS will handle the interrupt; for later, it will inform KVM.

KVM uses kvm_clock to read from a shared memory location (in VM) on which hypervisor KVM is periodically writing the time. So if you modify gettimeofday() on host, it will be used by hypervisor to get time and updated time will be written on shared memory location.

You can read more about KVM in original paper: [Paper](http://www.fujitsu.com/global/documents/about/resources/publications/fstj/archives/vol47-3/paper18.pdf)